# Is there a reason the RewriteRule [P] flag doesn't seem to work on DreamHost?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dreamhost

I am working on a wordpress site hosted on DreamHost.  There is a page on the wordpress site that has the stub 'profile' and uses a custom template that takes a URL parameter.  An example of a URL is:

```
http://www.example.com/profile?profileSubject=subject1
```

I am writing a RewriteRule in the htaccess file so that I can type a url like this:

```
http://www.example.com/profile/subject1
```

My RewriteRule in the htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/? http://www.example.com/profile?profileSubject=$1 [P,L]
```

This works insofar as typing the /profile/subject1 URL will load the content correctly, but, the URL in the address bar changes to the profile?profileSubject=subject1 URL.  I believe this is what the P flag(i.e. proxy) is supposed to be for, to stop the URL in the address bar from changing.

I happen to have a copy of the site I'm working on on my local server as well, so I tried putting the exact same line in the htaccess file for my local server, and there the P flag worked, and the URL in the address bar remained /profile/subject1 when the content was loaded.

So, my conclusion is that the P flag isn't working for some reason on Dreamhost, and I'm just wondering if anyone else has had a similar issue and/or if there's anything I can do here.

EDIT: Here is the requested result of logging a rewrite attempt:

```
[Fri Nov 25 14:37:29.213969 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1427] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:60404] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#7faf94036ef8][rid#7faf948656a0/initial] [perdir /Users/me/Sites/wordpress/] add path info postfix: /Users/me/Sites/wordpress/profile -> /Users/me/Sites/wordpress/profile/javonte-green
[Fri Nov 25 14:37:29.214037 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1427] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:60404] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#7faf94036ef8][rid#7faf948656a0/initial] [perdir /Users/me/Sites/wordpress/] strip per-dir prefix: /Users/me/Sites/wordpress/profile/javonte-green -> profile/javonte-green
[Fri Nov 25 14:37:29.214042 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1427] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:60404] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#7faf94036ef8][rid#7faf948656a0/initial] [perdir /Users/me/Sites/wordpress/] applying pattern '^/?profile/(.+)$' to uri 'profile/javonte-green'
[Fri Nov 25 14:37:29.214050 2022] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1427] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:60404] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#7faf94036ef8][rid#7faf948656a0/initial] [perdir /Users/me/Sites/wordpress/] rewrite 'profile/javonte-green' -> '/profile?profileSubject=javonte-green'
[Fri Nov 25 14:37:29.214056 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1427] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:60404] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#7faf94036ef8][rid#7faf948656a0/initial] split uri=/profile?profileSubject=javonte-green -> uri=/profile, args=profileSubject=javonte-green
[Fri Nov 25 14:37:29.214062 2022] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1427] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:60404] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#7faf94036ef8][rid#7faf948656a0/initial] [perdir /Users/me/Sites/wordpress/] trying to replace prefix /Users/me/Sites/wordpress/ with /~me/wordpress/
[Fri Nov 25 14:37:29.214067 2022] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1427] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:60404] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#7faf94036ef8][rid#7faf948656a0/initial] [perdir /Users/me/Sites/wordpress/] trying to replace context docroot /Users/me/Sites with context prefix /~me
[Fri Nov 25 14:37:29.214071 2022] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1427] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:60404] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#7faf94036ef8][rid#7faf948656a0/initial] [perdir /Users/me/Sites/wordpress/] internal redirect with /profile [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

EDIT 2: I finally figured it out.  The solution is to refer to the profile page via wordpress's index.php rather than the 'profile' stub:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.+)$ /index.php?pagename=profile&profileSubject=$1 [QSA]
```

Done this way, content loads correctly without changing the visible URL.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p: _"Note: mod_proxy must be enabled in order to use this flag."_ - perhaps that is simply not the case?

Comment: Also ... why do you want to use the proxy module for this? That means a full additional request each time. Why not a simple internal rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

As @CBroe pointed out in the comment to the question the proxy module has to be enabled inside the http server for the `P` flag to be available. Though I fail to understand how the outcome you describe could occur with that rule in place. Maybe you have other, additional rules responsible for the redirection you observe?

Why do you want to use the proxy module for this? That means a full additional request each time. And it appears not necessary to me from your description.

Why don't you use a simple internal rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.+)$ /profile?profileSubject=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That will keep the visible URL in the browser as `https://www.example.com/profile/subject1` while internally calling the resource `/profile?profileSubject=subject1`, how ever that one is going to get resolved.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  The relative path "/profile?profileSubject=$1" results in wordpress acting as if a page hasn't been found.  Nothing loads at all.   Changing the path to an absolute one(i.e. http:// etc) results in the page being loaded successfully, but also in the URL changing, which is the exact behavior I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I can't see any reason for that. You definitely do _not_ want to specify a full URL, that necessarily leads to an _external redirection_ which is not what you want. You want an internal rewrite, so you want a _path_ as a target. Assuming you did not alter the rule I posted and that the URLs you posted in the question do indeed have the actual structure (not an additional subfolder for example), then the rule _should_ work. If it does not you will have to enable rewrite logging to understand in detail what exactly is going  on inside your rewriting engine.

Comment: Oh, there is one thing that comes to mind here: it could be that above rule interacts with other rewriting rules you have in place. You did not mention any. But if there are other rules then certainly that might be something you need to take into account here. I can't help with that though, as long as you do not post those rules.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the relative path /profile is a wordpress stub, which depends on the default wordpress rewrite rules(the stuff between # BEGIN Wordpress and # END Wordpress) to resolve to anything because it's not an actual folder, just a wordpress stub.  So maybe because the rewrite rule we're working with comes before the wordpress rules, it's just not resolving.

Comment: So you _do_ have additional rewriting rules in place. OK. Have a try using the `END` flag instead of the `L` flag. So `RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.+)$ /profile?profileSubject=$1 [QSA,END]`.

Comment: That results in the error message "The requested URL /profile was not found on this server."  I think it's because profile isn't an actual folder but rather a wordpress stub.

Comment: That is very strange. It clearly should work with the original rule using the `L` flag. After that rewrite step the wordpress rules should get applied as if the target the request has been rewritten to has been sent by the browser originally. I fail to see an issue with that. This is the point where you need to enable rewrite logging in your http server. It allows to understand on a step by step base what is actually going on side your rewrite engine. But that is something you have to do, I can't do that for you. Please add the result to the question, then we'll have another look.

Comment: I have enabled rewrite logging on my local machine(I don't believe I have access to do it on DreamHost) and ran a test, and added the results to the end of my OP.  Nothing jumps out at me, but maybe you see something.

Comment: That shows that the rule gets applied and produces the expected and desired result. I have no idea where that last line comes from, though. That must be some other effect independent from request rewriting. I currently have no clue, sorry. What ever is responsible for that redirect, to me it sounds as if it drops the query argument. Which would explain the "not found" you get back.

Comment: I figured it out - I had to refer to the profile page as a parameter of index.php for wordpress to load it correctly on the internal redirect.  See the second edit to my OP.  Thanks for your time and effort, I appreciate it.

Comment: That should actually be done by the additional rules wordpress itself implements. If that does _not_ work, then this is an obvious bug in wordpress. Since it apparently implements two different strategies to evaluate requests, strategies that are in conflict. Anyway, glad you could solve your immediate issue!